# how can we have multitenant database in mongo db??

Tags: mongodb, multi-tenant

we are developing multitenant appication that runs on mongodb.So far i have seen the articles.one databse per tenant is not feasible.Any actual example would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You can have. You can switch the database as per the tenant ( say, through your application )

Comment: i m trying to keep same code base......I think maintaining different database for each tenant will reduce the scalability!!

Answer (score 0):

Having a database per tenant is one approach.

Alternatively, you can namespace your collections. Say, you have tenants A and B. Their collections for "users" will be in the same database, but called, for example, `a_users` and `b_users`.

Comment: I am quite new to this but as i can see,Your alternate solution seems fine.